# output stream doesn't make a file

Tags: java, file, file-writing

The code below is supposed to create and write to a file, but it doesn't create a file in my directory. Everything with the `Scanner` is working, it scans everything from `jTextField` perfectly.

```
OutputStream os;
try {
    os = new FileOutputStream("kurinys.dat");
    try (DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os)) {
        Scanner skanuoklisSaugojimui = new Scanner(jTextField1.getText());
        while(skanuoklisSaugojimui.hasNextInt()){
            int natosAukstis = skanuoklisSaugojimui.nextInt();
            dos.writeInt(natosAukstis);
        }
    }
    os.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Grafika.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Grafika.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Can someone please help me find the problem?

Comment: Could you please provide an explanation of what you're trying to do. I see you're initializing a scanner with the text in a JTextField, when does this occur? Is there text in the text field?

Comment: As I said, everything with scanner is ok and it scans everything from jTextField perfectly.

Comment: Does it throw an exception?

Comment: Why aren't you using the try-with-resources with `os` also, since you're closing it anyway...

Comment: Your code works on my computer. A number of things could be responsible for the problem your facing, but we don't have access to your computer, so solving the problem becomes a lot harder.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a nested try, it doesnt have any sense and could case a lot of problems in terms of exception handling.

```
OutputStream os;
 try {
os = new FileOutputStream("kurinys.dat");
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
}


try (DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os)) {
    Scanner skanuoklisSaugojimui = new Scanner(jTextField1.getText());
    while(skanuoklisSaugojimui.hasNextInt()){
        int natosAukstis = skanuoklisSaugojimui.nextInt();
        dos.writeInt(natosAukstis);
    }
}
os.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
Logger.getLogger(Grafika.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IOException ex) {
Logger.getLogger(Grafika.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```